# Exclude some X axis points from a chart vba

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts, axis

I have recorded a macro that creates a chart in Excel VBA.
However, if I click on the chart and go to 'Select data' I can tick or untick X-axis labels to take certain datapoints out of my chart. This hasn't been recorded in the macro.
How do I replicate this behaviour programmatically in vba?

Answer (score 0):

This code hides the first four data points:

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(1).IsFiltered = True
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(3).IsFiltered = True
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(4).IsFiltered = True
```